# Which version of XPath does Firefox support?

Tags: firefox, xpath

I am building a web scraper using Firefox with Selenium WebDriver, and I would like to use XPath expressions that exist only in XPath 2 and XPath 3.

Which version of XPath does Firefox support?

If it is XPath 1.0, is there any way to make Firefox support later versions?

---

*Note: The current version of Firefox as of writing is 47.0.*

Comment: IIRC virtually nobody (of relevance) supports later versions of XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Which version of XPath does Firefox support?

Firefox currently supports XPath 1.0.

There are no plans to support Xpath 2.0.

See [What browsers support Xpath 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658799/what-browsers-support-xpath-2-0) for some workarounds.

> Support for XPath varies widely; it's supported reasonably well in Firefox (although there are no plans to improve support further), while other browsers implement it to a lesser extent if at all.

Source [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)

There is an open (since 2007) bug report to add support for XPath 2.0:

> As Xpath 2.0 and Xslt 2.0 is a w3c recommendation, it would be a good idea to implement it into the engine.

Source [Bug 396966 - Xpath 2.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=396966)

---

#### Further Reading

- [What browsers support Xpath 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658799/what-browsers-support-xpath-2-0)

Comment: [Firefox bug for XPath 3.1](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1556141): "The effort required to implement newer versions of XPath and XSLT is pretty big and hard to justify given that they're little used technologies on the web. I also don't think any of the other browsers have signaled that they're interested in shipping support for newer versions."